# Splitting strings in python using import re

Tags: python, regex

Why does this work:

```
string = 'N{P}[ST]{P}'

>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"[\[\]]",  string)
>>> ['N{P}', 'ST', '{P}']
```

But this don't?

```
>>> re.split(r"{\{\}}", string)
```

Comment: I highly recommend you [regexr](http://regexr.com/3e483), it's a wonderful tool for learning regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
re.split(r"[{}]", string)
```

`r"{\{\}}"` is a special re syntax to repeat groups (ex: `(ab){1,3}` matches `ab`, `abab` or `ababab`) but not the character range (note that you don't have to escape the curly braces in a character range).
(I admit I don't know what your strange regex is supposed to do specially in the re.split context, but not what you want :))

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `}` are meta-characters in regular expressions and should be escaped or put into a character class
`{\{\}}` - means just escaped curly braces within unescaped

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you have an idea of what it does? (since it doesn't crash)